# Error en python y duda: Módulo de pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

**Error en el código con implementaciónes**

Por favor alguien me puede explicar el porqué del error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "level_1.py", line 186, in <module>
    lost = sb[score].click(event, letter)
NameError: name 'letter' is not defined
```

> El error se encuentra más debajo por donde pone: "click(self):"

Estoy tratando de hacer un piano titles que funcione únicamente con el input del teclado.
Alguien sabe cómo poner una linea que defina el rango de toque a lo Gitar Hero

(Una linea donde si la tecla negra pisa y es presionada la tecla definida, que sume puntos. Si no, que se pierda la partida)?

> ```
>    +----+
>    |    |
>    |    |
>    |    | => Zona donde caen las notas
>    |    |
>    +----+ => Línea de rango
>    |    | => Zona después de la linea
>    +----+
> ```

Por favor, necesito vuestra ayuda :(

Aquí está el siguiente código:

```
    import pygame
    import os
    from pygame.locals import *
    import random
    from random import seed
    
    from pyclimenu.menu import *
    
    wix = 450
    wiy = 750
    
    def message(screen, text, color=(55, 55, 55), size=36, pos=(-1, -1)):
        if pos[0] == -1:
            pos = (screen.get_rect().centerx,pos[1])
        if pos[1] == -1:
            pos = (pos[0], screen.get_rect().centery)
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, size)
        text = font.render(text, 1, color)
        textpos = text.get_rect()
        textpos.centerx = pos[0]
        textpos.centery = pos[1]
        screen.blit(text, textpos)
    
    
    def load_sound(name):
        if not pygame.mixer or not pygame.mixer.get_init():
            pass
        try:
            sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(name)
        except pygame.error:
            print('Cannot load sound: %s' % name)
            raise SystemExit(str(geterror()))
        return sound
    
    
    class button():
        x = 0
        y = -wiy // 5
        h = wix // 4 - 1
        l = wiy // 5
        enclick = True
    
        def pos(self, n):
            self.x = n * wix // 4
    
        def update(self, screen):
            if self.enclick:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), [self.x, self.y, self.h, self.l])
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (128, 128, 128), [self.x, self.y, self.h, self.l])
    
        def click(self, ps, key):
            events = pygame.event.get()
            
            a = pygame.K_a
            key.b = pygame.K_b
            key.c = pygame.K_c
            d = pygame.K_d
            key.e = pygame.K_e
            f = pygame.K_f
            key.g = pygame.K_g
            key.h = pygame.K_h
            key.i = pygame.K_i
            key.j = pygame.K_j
            key.k = pygame.K_k
            key.l = pygame.K_l
            key.m = pygame.K_m
            key.n = pygame.K_n
            key.o = pygame.K_o
            key.p = pygame.K_p
            key.q = pygame.K_q
            key.r = pygame.K_r
            s = pygame.K_s
            key.t = pygame.K_t
            key.u = pygame.K_u
            key.v = pygame.K_v
            key.w = pygame.K_w
            key.x = pygame.K_x
            key.y = pygame.K_y
            key.z = pygame.K_z
    
            map_key = [s, d, s, a, s, s, s, d, a, d, f, a, f, s, d, f, s, a, d, f, s, a, s, d, f, a, s, d, a]
            map_one = [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0]
    
            for event in events:
                for letter in map_key:
                    if event.key == letter:        
                        if ps[0] in map_one:
                            if ps[1] in map_key:
                                self.enclick = False
                                return 0
                
            return 1
    
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.get_init()
    
    mutrue = load_sound("data/punch.wav")  # punch.wav
    mufall = load_sound("data/boom.wav")  # boom.mp3
    
    #if play_function(level='1'):
    #    pygame.mixer.music.load("data/music_one.mp3")  # a.mp3
    #if play_function(level='2'):
    #    pygame.mixer.music.load("data/intro.mp3")  # a.mp3
    #if play_function(level='3'):
    #    pygame.mixer.music.load("data/music_one.mp3")  # a.mp3
    pygame.mixer.music.load('data/music_one.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((wix, wiy))
    
    # a = random.randint(4)
    
    star = pygame.image.load('data/star.png')
    ed_star = pygame.transform.scale(star, (30, 30))
    
    not_star = pygame.image.load('data/not_star.png')
    not_ed_star = pygame.transform.scale(not_star, (30, 30))
    
    hearth = pygame.image.load('data/hearth.png')
    ed_hearth = pygame.transform.scale(hearth, (45, 45))
    
    # Keyboard handler
    
    is_pause = False
    
    a_score = 10
    b_score = 25
    c_score = 35
    
    map_one = [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0]
    
    b = random.randint(50, 255)
    c = random.randint(100, 150)
    ac = random.randint(10, 200)
    aac = random.randint(0, 3)
    lost = 0
    time = 0
    delt = 60
    sb = []
    score = 0
    speed = 2
    
    while lost == 0:
        #for i in range (10):
        for i in map_one:
            sb.append(button())
            sb[-1].pos(i)  #(random.randrange(4))
            if lost != 0:
                break
    
            for j in range(wiy // (5 * speed)): #5 * seed
                time += 1 / delt
                clock.tick(delt)
    
                if aac == 3:
                    screen.fill((b, c, ac))
                if aac == 2:
                    screen.fill((c, ac, b))
                else:
                    screen.fill((ac, c, b))
    
                if lost != 0:
                    break
    
                for k in range(len(sb)):
                    try:
                        sb[k].y += speed
                        sb[k].update(screen)
                        """if sb[k].y > wiy + 40:
                            sb.remove(sb[k])"""
                        if sb[k].y > wiy - sb[k].l and sb[k].enclick == True:
                            lost = 1
                    except:
                        pass
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == QUIT or \
                       (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                        pygame.quit()
                        print("Game was closed")
                        
                    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        lost = sb[score].click(event, letter)
                        if lost == 0:
                            mutrue.play()
                        else:
                            score += 1
                            print("Loser!")
                    
                    elif event.type == pygame.ACTIVEEVENT: # пауза при сворачивании(в разработке)
                        if event.state == 6:
                            if event.gain == 0:
                                print("| window minimized")
                                is_pause = True
                            elif event.gain == 1:
                                print("| window opened")
                                is_pause = False
                                
                #     pygame.time.wait(1)
                message(screen, "SCORE " + str(score), color=(255, 55, 225), pos=(-1, 30))
                if score >= a_score:
                    screen.blit(ed_star, (20, 10))
                    # добавляем 1-ую звезду
                    if score >= b_score:
                        screen.blit(ed_star, (50, 10))
                        if score >= c_score:
                            screen.blit(ed_star, (80, 10))
                            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                            pygame.mixer.music.load("data/win.mp3")  # a.mp3
                            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
                            if aac == 3:
                                screen.fill((b, c, ac))
                            if aac == 2:
                                screen.fill((c, ac, b))
                            else:
                                screen.fill((ac, c, b))
                            message(screen, "YOU WIN!!!", color=(255, 55, 225), size=75, pos=(-1, -1))
                            pygame.display.update()
                            pygame.time.wait(4000)
                            quit()
                pygame.display.update()
        speed += 1
    
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("data/fail.mp3")  # a.mp3
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    if aac == 3:
        screen.fill((b, c, ac))
    if aac == 2:
        screen.fill((c, ac, b))
    else:
        screen.fill((ac, c, b))
    message(screen, "YOU LOSE ", color=(255, 55, 225), size=100, pos=(-1, -1))
    message(screen, "Your Score: " + str(score), color=(110, 118, 225), pos=(-1, wiy // 2 + 45))
    if score >= a_score:
        screen.blit(ed_star, (180, 435))
        screen.blit(not_ed_star, (215, 435))
        screen.blit(not_ed_star, (250, 435))
        if score >= b_score:
            screen.blit(ed_star, (215, 435))
            screen.blit(not_ed_star, (250, 435))
            if score >= c_score:
                screen.blit(ed_star, (250, 435))
    else:
        screen.blit(not_ed_star, (180, 435))
        screen.blit(not_ed_star, (215, 435))
        screen.blit(not_ed_star, (250, 435))
        print('no stars')
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(4000)
```

Comment: Puedes ser más específico? No queda claro cuál es la pregunta ://

Comment: este código es algo monstruoso, sería bueno que lo modularizaras para poder tratarlo mejor

Answer (score 1):

El error es que usas una variable `letter` que no está definida en ninguna parte.

La única parte donde aparece mencionada `letter` es en el método `button.click()`, pero esa variable deja de existir al salir del método.

En la línea donde ocurre el error:

```
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    lost = sb[score].click(event, letter)
```

estás reaccionando frente a un click, pero ¿de donde sale `letter`?

¿Por qué procesas MOUSEBUTTONDOWN si el juego funciona con teclado?